# Importing system modules in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, module

Background:

I'm writing a symbolic package aimed at pypy for representing expressions and taking derivatives. Not working on simplification or anything like that at the moment, just differentiation and evaluation.

Question:

I'm writing expression classes to represent many of the functions in math (sqrt, log, exp, sin, cos, etc, etc). I have named the module that this goes in `math` to coincide with the module where you natural find said function. I may in the future do the same with `cmath` and any other module of particular mathematical interest. My module is part of a larger package `ldb.algebra` so the name `math` isn't going to collide with anything at the base namespace. However, in order to evaluate expressions I'm going to need to import the system `math` module inside the `ldb.algebra.math` module, and I can't do this from inside my `math` module (or any other module at the same level of package for that matter). Here's my basic path so far:

```
ldb/
    __init__.py - empty
    algebra/
        __init__.py - empty
        math.py
```

Contents of ldb/algebra/math.py as an example of the problem:

```
import math

my_sin = math.sin
```

Obviously not terribly useful but it shows the idea. I'm using python2 (or rather pypy for python2). I've found that I can get around this by creating a subpackage, a module under that say `sys_math`, importing `math` in that module and exposing the necessary functions but this seems like a lot of work and an ugly mess.

**So my question is:** can I get at the system `math` module while still having a module called `ldb.algebra.math`? Perhaps something funny in the `__init__.py` file like making the module _math and then changing the name in `__init__.py` somehow, or some special way to import the system module instead of myself.

My ugly solution so far:

```
ldb/
    algebra/
        extra_package/
            __init__.py - empty
            sys_math.py
```

Contents of sys_math.py:

```
import math

sin = math.sin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

Put that at the top of your module to disable implicit relative imports. Then `import math` will import the built-in `math` module, and if you want to use relative imports, you have to do them explicitly with syntax like `from . import math`.

Comment: Yes much better idea; disable relative importing.

Comment: After fixing some unrelated issues that worked like a charm. Thanks. Also, thanks for the ref to pep-0328, I was wondering where all that stuff I remembered reading before was.